# Eager loading polymorphic relations in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am using `rappasoft/laravel-authentication-log` with my `User` model. It exposes the following polymorphic relation to the User model:

```
public function authentications()
{
    return $this->morphMany(AuthenticationLog::class, 'authenticatable')->latest('login_at');
}
```

Now, if I run `$user->authentications->some_property` (`$user` is from `User::get()` collection), it emits N+1 queries. How do I eager load this relationship?

I've tried `User::with('authentications')->get()` but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm still getting N+1 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It seems the eager loading is working as-is. I was using the `$user->getLastLoginAt()` method which loads the relationship explicitly:

```
    public function lastLoginAt()
{
    return optional($this->authentications()->first())->login_at;
}
```

I've changed the code to `optional($this->authentications->first())->login_at` and I'm no longer generatig N+1 queries